# Difference between 'lie' and 'lie down'

Tags: meaning, differences, phrasal-verbs, confusables

What is difference between **lie** and **lie down**? Please explain with some examples.

Comment: The question should have been: what is the difference between lie and lay.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Why, do you think?

Answer (score 6):

The verb **to lie** describes the *state* of being in a horizontal position.

> I often *lie* in bed for hours before falling asleep.
>
> Why are you *lying* on the floor?

The verb **to lie down** describes the *action* of going from an upright position to a horizontal position.

> You should *lie down* if you're feeling dizzy.
>
> She *lay down* on the grass and went to sleep.

For the verb form differences between *to lie* (be horizontal), *to lie* (tell an untruth) and *to lay* (to put flat), see [this article](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000877.html) from Professor Pullum on Language Log.

Comment: -1 Please see the definition for *lie down* --  "to place oneself or **be**" -- I wonder how this answer has been up voted!

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=%22been+lying+down%22&tbm=bks

Comment: @Kris, you are right to point out that in its continuous form (She's lying down; he's been lying down, etc.) the verb can also describe a state.

Comment: Which makes this 'not an answer', right?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=%22lie+down+any+longer%22&tbm=bks

Answer (score 2):

*[lie down](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lie-down)* is a phrasal verb, an expression and an idiom.
phrasal verb/ expression:

> 1 to place oneself or be in a prostrate position in order to rest or sleep

idiom:

> 2 to accept without protest or opposition (esp in the phrases *lie down under, take something lying down*)

*[lie](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lie)* <sup>2</sup>, on the other hand, is just an ordinary verb like any other.

> to be situated, esp on a horizontal surface   ⇒ "the pencil is lying on the desk", "India lies to the south of Russia"

Answer (score -2):

Lie, is to tell a none truth i.e. saying something that is false. 'I didn't eat your cookie.' (In this example you would have actually eaten the cookie)

Lie down, is to lay i.e. when someone says 'Lie down on the bed' they are giving you a command to lay down on the bed.

Comment: This answer does, in fact, describe a difference between the two terms. This answer could use a little fleshing out, though.

Comment: And keeping with the theme of unrelatedness, "lie down" also means "give up": _I will not lie down -- I will stand and fight!_

Comment: OED records first use of *to lie = be in a prostrate or recumbent position* in C11. It's misleading to suggest that sense only applies with the form *to lie **down***.